# I want to open the tab when I press on icon nn footer in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to open the tab of favorite or bookmark when I click on their icons placed at footer. Pls see my image thanks.

I want that when I click on bookmark or fav icon the tab of fav or bookmark should be open. I will give u the tabs code if u want

```
  <Right style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                      {/* favourutes bookmarks icon */}
                      <Icon
                        name="ios-heart-empty"
                        style={{margin: 5, fontSize: 28}}
                      />
                      <Icon
                        name="bookmark"
                        style={{margin: 5, fontSize: 28}}
                      />
                      <Icon
                        name="download"
                        style={{margin: 5, fontSize: 28}}
                      />
                    </Right>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are sharing your requirement here. you should be  specific while posting a question here, i.e what did you are trying to achieve and what did you try to achieve this and what problem you are facing in achieving this.

Comment: updated. Pls look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add onPress={()=> function()} to Icon
Add paas any function or navigate to page as per your requirement
E.g,

```
               name="download"
               style={{margin: 5, fontSize: 28}}
               onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('bookmark')}
            />
```